# lean-and-mean CORBA mock server

Tags: mocking, tdd, portability, corba

We're planning to create a CORBA client on several platforms. For integration testing, it would be useful to be able to have a CORBA service to mock the 'real' thing.

I'm currently looking into what can be used to create such a service.  Since performance of the server is not crucial, but agility is, I tried to find out about omniORBpy (which I didn't yet manage to set up on this mac) and fnorb (which seems kinda in a coma).

Is there a live, easy-to-use, portable, CORBA implementation that can easily be integrated into test frameworks?

Comment: There is also R2CORBA, a CORBA implementation for Ruby/JRuby. It uses TAO/JacORB as underlying ORB which is used for handling all communication, so interoperability shouldn't be a problem. You can easily create implementations, even no need to run an IDL compiler as part of the job. See http://osportal.remedy.nl for the download of it, see http://www.orbzone.org for several articles about R2CORBA.

Comment: omniORBpy is awesome for this kind of thing.

Comment: @BrianNeal: somehow, I didn't get it running on mac OSX, though.  Any experience with that?

Comment: No, I've used it on Linux, Cygwin, & Windows. It isn't hard to build from source on Linux either. Sorry.

Comment: You might ask for help on building omniORB on OSX on the mailing list.

Comment: "omniORBpy (which I didn't yet manage to set up on this mac)" What's the symptom? omniORBpy normally works like charm.